# Hi, I'm facing a blocker in a SonarQube violation - Disable access to external entities in XML parsing

Tags: java, sonarqube, saxon, illegalargumentexception, xxe

Tried with the fix given in sonarqube.

```
        *TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        tfactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        tfactory.setAttribute(javax.xml.XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
        return tfactory;*
```

But I'm facing a runtime exception on setAttribute:
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration property [http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD"](http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD%22)

This seems to be because of a bug in the version of saxon jar im using [9.7] . And its working fine on saxon 10.3 . Please refer https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4729 for this bug.

Below are my questions:

1. Is there any way to make it work on my existing saxon version (without upgrading it to 10.x). Tried using transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true) but sonarqube is not satisfied as it expects above fix.
2. If upgrading to 10.x is the only way, then below is the challenge im facing:

   I'm overriding a method from TraceListener for some business logics. But the method signature
   got changed on latest version like below:

   Class - net.sf.saxon.lib.TraceListener

   Saxon 9.7 -> public void enter(InstructionInfo instruction, XPathContext context)

   Saxon 10.x -> public void enter(Traceable instruction,
   java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> properties, XPathContext context)

   My current Code:

   ```
   *@Override
   public void enter(InstructionInfo instruction, XPathContext context) {
    int data = instruction.getConstructType();
    if ((data == 155) || (data == 200)) {
        .......logic......
    }
   }*
   ```

My new code will be :

```
   *@Override
   public void enter(Traceable instruction,           
    java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> properties, XPathContext context){
    --> what to use here for getConstructType()
    if ((data == 155) || (data == 200)) {
        .......logic......
    }
   }*
```

So the problem is 10.x jar doesn't have getConstructType() method in its Traceable class or InstructionInfo class. How do I use getConstructType() in 10.x version?

P.S : It will be very helpful if the 1st question gets answered i.e) if I can be able to resolve with my current version of jar as new version requires testing of all the functionalities throughout the project :(  Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like Sonar is detecting a legitimate error, and asking you to fix it by updating your version of the library. And you would prefer not to update, because then you would need to test more things because the code would be different. Yes, it will be more work to update, but any other answer will also require work (for example, backporting a fix for the bug and tricking Sonar into accepting it) -- and as libraries continue to change, it will be even harder to keep your code up to date. So, in short: update your library version.

Comment: Hi @tucuxi , thans for the detailed info. One question here:
The 10.3 version of this interface replaces InstructionInfo with Traceable --> How do I use getConstructType() in this version or what's the alternative for this, like i asked in the second question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First point: to be a little argumentative, it is NOT a bug in Saxon 9.7. The Javadoc for TransformerFactory (in Java 8) says "All implementations that implement JAXP 1.5 or newer are required to support the XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET properties." but Saxon 9.7 never claimed to implement JAXP 1.5, it only claimed to implement JAXP 1.3.

Saying "I want to stay on an old release of Saxon but I can't, because I want a version that supports a new feature of JAXP" is very understandable, but not actually very logical.

One solution to this is to add your own implementation of the TransformerFactory API, which intercepts the attempt to set this property and doesn't pass it on to Saxon.

Note that this property is in the wrong place anyway. DTD processing is the responsibility of the XML parser, not the XSLT processor. The specification doesn't make it clear exactly what effect it's supposed to have. If the XSLT processor instantiates the XML parser, it seems reasonable that it should pass the property on, but what should it do if it's not accepted? And should it pass it on at all if the XML parser is created by the user application rather than by the XSLT processor? Generally it's a very frustrating exercise trying to implement rules like this in the JAXP specification, which are often very fuzzily specified.

I would encourage you generally to try to keep abreast of new Saxon releases to avoid hitting problems which have already been solved. Yes, it's true that we occasionally revise the design of some of the "system programming" interfaces such as the `TraceListener` interface. The 10.3 version of this interface replaces `InstructionInfo` with `Traceable`, and to find out what kind of `Traceable` is involved, you should use `instanceof`.

When we do make changes, we often introduce a new API in one major version and drop the old API in the following version. If you jump forward three major releases in one go (9.7 to 10, skipping 9.8 and 9.9) then you're not able to take advantage of these transition aids.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kay , thanks for the detailed info. if saxon 9.7 uses Jaxp 1.3, I understand from your answer that, we cannot disable access to external entity in this version, pls correct me if I'm wrong. 
One question here:
The 10.3 version of this interface replaces InstructionInfo with Traceable --> How do I use getConstructType() in this version or what's the alternative for this (the second question in my posted query)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can disable access to external entities by supplying your own XMLReader instance (e.g. in a SAXSource) and configuring it yourself, rather than relying on Saxon to do so; or by setting an EntityResolver in various interfaces.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous response, you can use "instanceof" on the Traceable.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Michael . Sorry I'm asking more but I'm a newbee here , so any example with "instanceof" wud be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Your code does `if ((data == 155) || (data == 200)) {`, which I think corresponds to `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:template` in Saxon 9.9, though the numbers probably changed from one release to another, which was a major reason for changing the interface. In 10.x use `traceable instanceof ForEach`, `traceable instanceof NamedTemplate`, `traceable instanceof TemplateRule`. I'm afraid the names are still poorly documented, but they're a bit more likely to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tf.setAttribute(“http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD”,””);
tf.setAttribute("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet",””);
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
```

reference: https://community.veracode.com/s/article/Java-Remediation-Guidance-for-XXE